# Type Error: context.getters.Function is not a function with Vuex

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I have tried so many ways to solve this buggy thing. Why does it say that this getters function doesn't exist although it exists

action.js

```
//Module's Actions Functions

export const services_addService = (context, payload) => {
    payload.person = context.getters.contacts_getPersonById(payload.id).person
    let dataDB = context.getters.services_getSort(0);
    let currentDB = dataDB.filter(element => element.person == payload.person);
    let oldDB = context.getters.services_getSort(1).filter(element => element.person == payload.person)
    let getCurrentworker = dataDB.find(element => element.person == payload.person && (element.start == payload.start || element.end == payload.end))

    if(currentDB.length == 0){
        if(getCurrentworker.length == 0){
            commit('addService', payload)
        }
        else {
            commit('replaceService', {key: dataDB.indexOf(getCurrentworker) , data: payload})
        }
    }
    else {
        commit('replaceService', {key: oldDB.indexOf(getCurrentworker), data: payload})
    }
};
```

getters.js

```
//Module's Getters Functions

/** Get Contacts */
export const contacts_getData = state => state.contacts.sort(function(a, b){return a.pos - b.pos});

/** Get Contacts Length */
export const contacts_getLength = state => state.contacts.length

/** Get Contact by ID  */
export const contacts_getPersonById = (state,getters,id) => {
    return state.contacts.find(element => {            
        element.id == id
    })
}
```

I've tried certain getters params like

```
export const contacts_getPersonById = state => id => {
        return state.contacts.find(element => {            
            element.id == id
        })
}
```

And this is my Error in Firefox

```
TypeError: context.getters.contacts_getPersonById is not a function[Learn More]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The test function you are passing to `state.contacts.find` should return a boolean. You are just comparing `element.id == id` but not returning anything.

So change it to:

```
export const contacts_getPersonById = state => id => {
  return state.contacts.find(element => {
    return element.id == id;
  });
```

};

or just

```
export const contacts_getPersonById = state => id => {
  return state.contacts.find(element => element.id == id);
};
```

Comment: U were right I forgot it. But I changed it to this and it still says the same :/                /** Get Contact by ID  */
export const contacts_getPersonById = (state,getters,id) => {
    return state.contacts.find(element => {            
        return element.id == id
    })
}

Comment: @EGNdev don't put the id as a param in getters. Do it as I showed